# Setting a variable in a QlineEdit PyQT

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qlineedit

I need to put a value of an element ( float) of a list into a QlineEdit of GUI i developed with Qt Designer.

```
raw = self.model_lineEdit.text()  
print('raw : ', raw)
ic,E = zip(*[ list(map(float,line.split(", "))) for line in raw.split("\n") ])
E,ic = np.array(E),np.array(ic)
self.Eoff1_lineEdit.setText(E[3])
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Can someone help me please ?
Thank you in advance and have a good day :) !

Comment: are you actually writing a string? try `self.Eoff1_lineEdit.setText(str(E[3]))`

Comment: Thank you Gsk, it works :) !

Comment: I add it as an answer; accept it if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is because you are actually trying to write something different from a string.

To ensure that your data is passed as string, you have to use

```
self.Eoff1_lineEdit.setText(str(E[3]))
```

instead of

```
self.Eoff1_lineEdit.setText(E[3])
```